# Как лучше хранить и обрабатывать файлы во View Django?

Tags: python, django

Допустим, я хочу использовать какой-нибудь статический файл не для вывода на страницах сайта, а для внутренних процессов. Ну, например, разбирать какую-нибудь эксельку или json. Где принято хранить такие файлы внутри проекта? И как принято их открывать внутри view? Получать путь до корневой папки из настроек проекта или еще как-то?

Comment: view — это всего лишь прослойка между браузером и бизнес-логикой, и не надо ничего открывать в view

Comment: @andreymal а как и где это лучше организовать? Просто в отдельном модуле, а во вью получать готовый результат? Как лучше получать путь до файла, чтобы его открыть?

Comment: Да, в отдельном модуле (и чтобы этот отдельный модуль ничего не знал про браузер во славу MVC). Какой путь — не знаю

Comment: Я для таких целей использую папку `services`